# Plants Vs Zombies Progress disappearing (Android)

Tags: android, plants-vs-zombies

I used to have plants vs Zombies on my Old Phone, when babysitting I let my cousin play it seeing she loves the mini games. But when I got a new phone the progress I made got wiped when I transferred the game. So I had to restart and unlock all the mini games again so she can play them.... was almost done but yesterday my entire progress got wiped and I had to start again with 1-1 (no not adventure mode 2).

Is there a way to recover this? (maybe using my old phone's files if it stores any there).
And why/how did this happen in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If you logged in with Google Play Games your progress should be saved in the cloud. Try to log out and login again.

If you want to recover the savegame from the old phone itself, look at `/sdcard/Android/data/com.popcap.pvz/files/userdata`

It should work by just copying the files.

Comment: Not every Android uses /sdcard/, I think

Comment: Tried it but the problem is it requires Root access on both devices... also Google Play Games cloud solution does NOT support PvZ anymore for some reason...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - /sdcard/ is the normal "directory" for Android User home-directory. It's basically the first folder you see when you are opening a file explorer.